# swt application not getting launched also no errors displayed

Tags: java, swt

For some users when they are trying to run my swt app, its just adding an icon in the windows taskbar.  Its not opening the shell window nor the title is displayed along with the icon in the task bar.

I tried to launch the app from the command prompt, no error message is displayed after I issued the command

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

My build environment and the target environment has the same version of Java.  What could be the reason. Unable to crack it.

-Subramanian S.

Comment: Can you provide any more details? `For some users` - what do these users have in common? (What OS are they running on, what JRE, etc.).

Comment: Sorry here are the details.  Both the users have the same enterprise deployed win 7  64.  JRE 1.8